# Logging hierarchy and appending the Spark log4j Logger to it

Tags: java, python, logging, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a main script and other module files in python, which are at the moment all in one folder.
I am trying to inject the logging messages now everywhere, but I don't really understand the logging hierarchy python although I have been reading up on it.

1. So just to check, since this is what happened from my tests:
   If I configure a logger on my main module, the logging of the modules I import to this main module are automatically appended to it, as long as I call the logger with `logging.getLogger(__name__)`, right? So the imported modules don't have to be in a subfolder or something?
2. I use PySpark in my script, so I create a Spark Session as recommended in Spark > 2.0, and use that in my modules. However, I want the Spark logger to be configured like my script's logger, and output its messages together with my module's logger onto a file or whatever handler I configure.

Until now I could only find that I can get the Spark logger through

```
log4jLogger = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j
LOGGER = log4jLogger.LogManager.getLogger(__name__)
```

But I don't want to use log4j for my logging, but the opposite. I want Spark's logger to be appended to my logger, which would be the parent logger.

Besides, even if I do use Spark's log4j, I don't want to change the logging configuration for the whole Spark by using a static log4j.properties file in the conf directory, but I want to log depending on the calling script.

Is there any way to do this? If not, then what is the best way to combine these two loggers into one configuration and output?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your post was fine, so there's no need to apologise for being a beginner at the start of your post (I've edited that out for you). Good luck in finding an answer!

Answer (score 2):

Configuring spark to forward logs to python logger is not possible - python and spark jvm are separated processes.

But, as you noticed, you can log events from pyspark to log4j (on driver only) by using py4j gateway. Your log4j configuration does not need to be static for all scripts, you can create many log4j configurations and load them at runtime:

```
./bin/spark-submit --driver-java-options \
     '-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/tmp/custom_logging.properties' script.py
```

If you run your application inside YARN using `yarn-cluster` remember about sending configuration file using `--files`, for example:

```
./bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster \
    --driver-java-options '-Dlog4j.configuration=file:logging.properties' \
    --files /tmp/logging.properties script.py
```

Comment: I see, thanks. Just to be sure though from the wording: I understand that configuring spark itself to forward logs is not possible, but does this also mean that it is also not possible to configure the properties file and capture these messages **from** python through the py4j gateway? Furthermore, if I use Spark's py4j, would it also work the same as python regarding the hierarchy if I call the logger at each module through `getLogger(__name__)`? And finally, can I get the logger in the beginning of the module or do I need to create a SparkContext first?

Comment: Ah yes, one more question: Does py4j also disable existing loggers if I import modules which also import the logger at the top, and then get the root logger from the main module? Or does it not matter since the configuration is done from the very beginning when calling spark-submit? More importantly, how do I import the py4j logger in submodules if the context is in the main module?

Comment: OK, so I tried to use the log4j Logger for my messages. I added the configuration file to the submit parameters, and it does find it. I used the default properties template from spark, with `rootCategory=INFO`, however every time I run the script, I get the message `Setting default log level to "WARN".` in the beginning. If I change the formatting or other options from the verbose section of this custom properties file, e.g. `log4j.logger.org.spark_project.jetty=INFO`, they show up, but the rootLogger remains at WARN, and I can't see my custom INFO messages.

Comment: Capturing log messages from python logging module to log4j is not possible, on driver you can call log4j via py4j. If you spark context is in main application module, get log4j logger object and pass it to the submodules, logging should work. This `Setting default log level to "WARN"` message is from `pyspark-shell`, use `spark-submit` to fully load requested log4j.properties.

Comment: OK, thanks again very much. I have not yet tried it on the cluster since it is not ready. At the moment I can only use an Eclipse Environment on Windows. So I added the `--master local[*] --queue PyDevSpark2.0.1 --driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:C:/log4j.properties"  pyspark-shell` to the `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` environment variable, and I get the first message. if I change `pyspark-shell` to `spark-submit`, or remove it completely, I get an exception: `Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number`. Would you happen to know how I can make it work here?

Comment: If not, then are you saying that this would not be a problem at all if I run it on the cluster with `spark-submit`

Comment: "Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number" tells that something is broken with spark context initialization, you should debug this first. Then custom log4j should in both local and cluster environments.

Comment: This comes also in the beginning: `Error: Cannot load main class from JAR file:/path/to/project/spark-submit`. I initialize the context in the script with `SparkSession.builder.appName('Name').getOrCreate()`. Why would it work with `pyspark-shell` and not with `spark-submit`? I'm sorry for the many questions, I'm new at the whole Hadoop scene. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Try looking for solution and then - if none found - ask a question. I've found solution to your error message by one google search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209299/cannot-load-main-class-from-jar-file-in-spark-submit

Comment: Yes, but you see, it is somehow looking for a jar file in a "spark-submit" folder, which doesn't make any sense at all. Unless I don't understand your link, it is a similar error message but for a different cause. The whole script executes fine with `pyspark-shell` appended in the end, but gives this error message when appending `spark-submit`instead. If this is simply a Windows problem, and it will work normally in a cluster, then it's ok, otherwise I don't understand.

Comment: No, it won't run in cluster if your `spark-submit` execution is failing in local mode. Please read the spark documentation on submitting jobs http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html and check if you way of running `spark-submit` is valid.